# Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish 22.04.2 stuck at 5.15.0-72-generic says there are no more updates

Tags: apt, updates

Upgraded a Dell compute node from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 with do-release-upgrade. Everything went fine, but now when I do an "apt update" after the upgrade the system reports "All packages are up to date.". However, I know this is not to be the case as the other nodes in this cluster updated to 5.19.0-42-generic. All the nodes have gone through the same upgrade process but this last one is stuck at 5.15.0-72-generic and thinks there are no more updates.

Anyone every experience this before and have a fix?

Comment: Maybe you dIdn't have 20.04 HWE and thus didn't get 22.04 HWE. If so look up how to install HWE kennels for 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the HWE kernel line (HardWare Enablement), then install it:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

For Ubuntu 22.04, this will give you kernel 5.19 as of point release 22.04.2.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.